# Tkinter won't draw rectangles on Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to initialise a grid of blue rectangles at a size specified by the user. However, the rectangles are not drawing on the initialised canvas. I'm trying to store them in a matrix for later manipulation. My code is as follows:

```
import Tkinter
import sys
from math import floor

master = Tkinter.Tk()

xboxes = int(sys.argv[1])
yboxes = int(sys.argv[2])

winx = 800
winy = 600

w = Tkinter.Canvas(master, width=winx, height=winy)

squares = [[None]*5 for i in range(5)]
w.pack()
for i in range(yboxes):
    for j in range(xboxes):
        initx = floor(winx / xboxes * j)
        inity = floor(winy / yboxes * i)
        sizex = floor(winx / xboxes * j)
        sizey = floor(winy / yboxes * i)
        squares[i][j] = w.create_rectangle(initx, inity, sizex, sizey, fill="red")

master.mainloop()
```

Any idea why it isn't working? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3.x ? In Python 3.x `Tkinter`  module is renamed to `tkinter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented changed parts with `# <--`.

[`create_rectangle`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_rectangle-method) accepts `x1, y1, x2, y2` (not `x, y, xsize, ysize`).

```
try:
    import Tkinter
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as Tkinter
import sys
from math import floor

master = Tkinter.Tk()

xboxes = int(sys.argv[1])
yboxes = int(sys.argv[2])

winx = 800
winy = 600

w = Tkinter.Canvas(master, width=winx, height=winy)

squares = [[None]*xboxes for i in range(yboxes)] # <-- changed hard-coded 5; to use passed argument
w.pack()
for i in range(yboxes):
    for j in range(xboxes):
        initx = floor(winx / xboxes * j) # <--
        inity = floor(winy / yboxes * i) # <--
        endx = floor(winx / xboxes * (j+1)) # <-- with `j`, It draw dot instead of rectangle.
        endy = floor(winy / yboxes * (i+1)) # <--
        squares[i][j] = w.create_rectangle(initx, inity, endx, endy, fill="red")

master.mainloop()
```